# How do I exclude "Local pickup only" listings from an eBay search?

Tags: ebay

For certain searches, a large percentage of results are available for "**local pickup only**" and **not local**.  It's not good UX to have to look carefully at each of hundreds of listings to find one that might offer shipping.

E-bay allows you to filter to show ONLY listings that offer **free local pickup** (one can also go to Craigslist instead of eBay), but what I'm looking for here is to **EXCLUDE** those listings that don't offer any shipping.

E-bay also allows you to put a filter on the distance by a radius from a ZIP code, but that excludes items that are far away and offer shipping (which is what I'm looking for).

E-bay also allows you to filter to just those offering free shipping, but since local pickup counts as free shipping, the "local pickup only" items are still there.

I've seen people use hacks like adding *(-"cash on collection",-"buyer must collect",-"collection only",-"no postage",-"pick up only",-"unable to post",-"needs to be collected",-"Collection in Person only",-"can't post")* to their queries, but this only filters some listings, namely those using those keywords, and for a lot of listings it's **only** in the shipping field that they say "local pickup only."

How can one see a set of search results EXCLUDING "local pickup only" items?

- Is it possible with the eBay interface?
- Can some magic word be added to a search query?
- Has someone written a supplementary page with an eBay API call, that filters those results out?
- Is there a user script somewhere that does the trick?

---

*Similar to: [How do I exclude "Part of a live auction event" listings from an eBay search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86239/how-do-i-exclude-part-of-a-live-auction-event-listings-from-an-ebay-search?lq=1)*

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a Google Chrome extension to solve this very problem. Here are the links for both UK and US versions. If they do well, I'll make versions for the rest of the world. 
I know this was asked 11 months ago, I hope someone still finds it useful.

[USA Version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nocollect-usa/mcnglccdlpanppjaonmoggiccdnckjjf)

[UK Version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nocollect/hdkgohohlhglacdiobiphiamjpdhkbgp)

Comment: Thanks!  Is the source code posted anywhere?

Comment: As raised by new user @RossHamilton, the links are now returning 404 (Not Found) errors.