# How do I exclude "Part of a live auction event" listings from an eBay search?

Tags: ebay

For certain searches, a large percentage of results are "Part of a live auction event on < date >" and not actually available for bidding outside a few minutes a few days later when the auction comes up in the live listing (and is further subject to ~20% added fees!).  How do I filter those out of the search results?

Note: Filtering to Auction in the Format selector doesn't help.

---

*Similar to: [How do I exclude "Local pickup only" listings from an eBay search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79849/how-do-i-exclude-local-pickup-only-listings-from-an-ebay-search)*

Answer (score 1):

Add "-lot" to the end of the search query to remove items that specify a lot number in the title, which items in live auction events often do.

It's not a perfect solution, especially if the item you're looking for is often sold in a "lot" of more than one item, but it helps quite a bit.